# What does the jQuery method $.on return?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does the jQuery method $.on return?

Example:

```
$(document).on("CustomEvent", CustomFunction);
```

Comment: `let x = $(document);
x === x.on('foo', x => x); // true`

Comment: did you read this article http://api.jquery.com/on/ ?

Comment: The jQuery documentation will tell you exactly what it returns...

Comment: As @AlexFilatov and @Goose point out - the documentation will tell you. To make it simpler, it will return a jQuery object of the element you are working with - in your case it will return `$(document)`. This allows for chaining commands `$('div').on('click', function(){ alert('hello'); }).css('background-color', 'blue');` will both attach a click listener to all `<div>` elements on the page to alert with 'hello' when clicked, then set the background color of the `<div>` elements to blue.

Comment: You should have ONE question per question.  It appears you have two questions here.  The first is in the title and the first sentence and in the code example.  The second question is something much more complicated in all the rest of the question.  Please remove this second question from this question and, if you still need help with it, post it in a new question.  Also, the second question needs code examples to clarify for us what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @AlexFilatov I did read that article but it was not clear to me what jQuery meant in the context of a return.

Comment: @mark.hch thanks, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, I will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the jQuery method $.on return?

`$(document).on(...)` returns the jQuery object created by `$(document)`.  This makes it chainable as in:

```
$(document).on("click", clickHandler).on("hover", hoverHandler);
```

In fact all jQuery methods that don't have a specific value to return will return the jQuery object so they can be chainable in this fashion.

Another commonly used example:

```
$("#target").fadeIn(2000).delay(5000).fadeOut(2000);
```

But, a method that has a specific value to return such as `.prop()` or `.attr()` will return that specific value:

```
var isChecked = $("#myCheckbox").prop("checked");
var imgSrc = $("#myImg").attr("src");
```

The return value for any jQuery API is listed in the documentation (here's a screen shot from the [doc page for `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

[image]

---

If you want to prevent an event handler from getting called again, you can either use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) which will only trigger the event once or you can use [`.off(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the event handler as desired or you can use some sort of flag in your own code to tell the event handler whether it should do its work or not.

The cleanest architectural solution to preventing repeat calls to something triggered by `.load()` is to move the event handler setup code to a different area of your Javascript so it is not loaded again by `.load()` and is only loaded once by the parent page.  That way it only gets called once.  Exactly how to do that depends upon the specific circumstances of your design which you have not disclosed so we can't advise more specifically than that.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery .load causing some repeating actions in page. if i am not wrong, you have to call your callback function inside "promise"

example

```
$(document).on("click", ".someClass", function () {

    //do something


    }).promise().done(function() {
        //your callback function
    });
});
```